# M-V-VM and BackgroundWorker

Tags: wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker

In my app, the BackgroundWorker (housekeeping task) checks for data to be deleted from the database. After the data has been deleted do I then remove that DataItem from the ViewModel or the Model?

(Yes, I'm new to MVVM and perhaps I don't understand it too well yet).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your model and your view model are implemented, but conceptually, I'd

- remove the data from the model, which, in turn, should

  - cause the data to be removed from the database and
  - cause the view models to be notified, so that they can update their state appropriately.

Comment: ok, so my ViewModels have to listen for changes to the Model right?

Comment: Exactly. I'm aware that this is not always an option, which is why I wrote that the solution might depend on how the model is implemented. Another option would be to have the viewmodels reload the model regularly, which might be required anyway if you have multiple instances of your application (on different PCs) accessing the same database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I would caution about the Background Worker modifying the viewmodel as part it's DoWork method.  Modifying the ViewModel suggests a change to the UI, which likely won't work since the DoWork method is not running on the UI thread.